# How to validate an inserted record before a delete on a Mysql Event

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySql event that works perfect but I would like to validate if the record was inserted before the delete just to make sure that I won't loose the record.

This is the MySql event:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE 
    EVENT IF NOT EXISTS respaldoRegRawInformeAperturaLocal
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2017-08-03 22:00:00' 
    DO BEGIN

    -- INSERT INTO BACKUP TABLE
    INSERT INTO regRawInformeAperturaLocalBACKUP (regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId) 
    -- GET DATA
    SELECT regRawInformeAperturaLocalId, rawInformeAperturaLocal, done, date, deviceId  
    FROM    regRawInformeAperturaLocal 
WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

    -- DELETE DATA FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    DELETE FROM regRawInformeAperturaLocal WHERE date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH);

END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Is there any way to validate if the records were inserted before the delete?

Comment: If the insert has an error the delete will not be called.
You could do a select count on how many rows are in the backup table versus how many the select from the main table find but I don't know why it would be needed.  
I don't think you want to use NOW() in 2 different places, you want to assign it to a variable and use the same date in both SQLs.
Maybe a better way to do it is `delete from regRawInformeAperturaLocal where regRawInformeAperturaLocalId in (select regRawInformeAperturaLocalId from regRawInformeAperturaLocalBACKUP )`  That will only delete rows in the backup table.

Comment: That's a really nice point. I'm going to implement this delete.